# How to use rails webpack loaded js in js erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, webpacker

I am using webpacker gem in rails 5.0 app, but I can't get the javascript to execute/be available in the js.erb I'm hitting on validation error.  I'm sure that I'm violating some simple premise here, but can't find the answer and no compile or console errors are present. I do have the `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` in my application.html.erb

Here is the setup:

app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```
import * as CustomerSession from 'customer_sessions';
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker');
```

app/javascript/customer_sessions/index.js:

```
export { univgwTabs } from './univgwTabs';
```

app/javascript/customer_sessions/univgwTabs:

```
export let univgwTabs = () => {
  console.log('hi');
};
```

js erb template called on validation error of form:

```
$("#right_side_right_bottom_target").html("<%= j render partial: 'generic_object_new' %>");
CustomerSession.univgwTabs();
Global.resizeWindow();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no issue with `console.log(CustomerSession)` in the location where you are importing it then the simplest fix I found was to just assign the imported variable as one of the global windows properties.

```
// in packs/application.js (or wherever your pack is)
// import
import * as CustomerSession from 'customer_sessions';

// assign
window.CustomerSession = CustomerSession
```

Assuming that there is no issues with webpacker, you should now be able to `console.log(CustomerSession)` in the console or your `js.erb` file.